# Eglot - JSON RPC Connection Error 32606 "Internal Error"

Tags: microsoft-windows, eglot

I've been wanting to get Eglot working so that I may use its LSP for my classes and in the future. Right now I'm trying to get it working for Python and I have pyright installed with pip (as well as node as the GitHub repo stated I'd need that installed).

As the title says, when Eglot is trying to connect to the server, I get a jsonrpc error:

```
[client-reply] (id:0) ERROR Mon Nov 20 09:19:00 2023:
(:jsonrpc "2.0" :id 0 :error)
        (:code -32603 :message "Internal error"))
```

I so far haven't found any solutions on how to fix this. I'm using Windows Emacs 28.2

Comment: Is pyright in your path? aka in command window type ```where pyright``` and see what the answer is, if it is part of your path.

Comment: @Ian I got a path to pyright so it seems to be in some path

Comment: You must verify/add the pyright path to your system path, to be found by eglot. Will be useful to show your configuration.